# using SquishIt with web resources

Tags: asp.net, webforms, squishit

I'm using the SquishIt to manage the js/css files and it works perfect, but only with my manually created files. How can I use it with the asp.net webresources/script resources (scripts for ajax, validation etc.) which are returned to browser throught the script manager?

Answer (score 0):

A method on bundles called .AddRootEmbeddedResource has been added to deal with situations like this (where an embedded resource does not use the default AssemblyName.ResourceName convention)